# Switch Partition to a different Instance

Tags: sql-server, ssis, partitioning

Is it possible to move a partition of a partitioned table to a different instance of SQL Server that is running on a different machine ? If yes how?

The goal is avoid using SSIS data flows and move the entire partition to another instance/machine. Probably the file containing the partition should be moved/copied from the file system to the other machine.

What are other options for achieving the above stated goal?

Comment: Answer is yes. It is possible to move the partition of a partitioned table. Not sure how this is related to SSIS though? Are you looking to perform this as a scheduled job?

Comment: Yes monthly job to archive a partition. How is it possible to move it to another instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWITCH PARTITION is part /option of alter table command and there is no way to refer tables from another Instance or machine directly directly.

Note : We can access using linked server but that is not direct.